# Remote control a (lightweight) browser with Python

Tags: python, linux, browser, raspberry-pi

Back in the days Netscape had a feature that allowed you to remote-control a browser-session from the command line (using '-remote' flag). I'm looking for a similar feature, but in a modern browser.

A more modern example of what I want to accomplish, but in a different application is Mplayer's [slave mode](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt).

The idea is that I want to be able to remote-control the browser from a Python-script, and do things like load pages, and reload the current page.

Ideally, it should be a lightweight browser (such as Midori) and the reason is that it will run on a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/). For the same reason, something like browser-control using Selenium won't work.

Many browsers are already able to accept URLs and various settings from command-line variables, but once the browser is up and running, you can't control it.

I do realize that one could write a simple browser based on existing libraries, but I was hoping that there was an existing solution I could tap into.

Also, just grabbing the page and render it as an image isn't sufficient, as pages can be dynamic (such as slideshows).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: To be able to remote-control multiple displays from a central point. Let's say you have a company with multiple branches and you have screens installed on each branch. Someone on HQ would then be able to push out information to these screens. Web-pages would then be one type of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [Uzbl](http://uzbl.org/).  It's made to be instrumented via sockets/FIFOs/etc., has no chrome of its own, etc.

We use it at my workplace for dashboards around the office.